# Plotting two curves in one plot, each over a separate domain

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I have six expressions (`savA`, `savB` and `depr` & `savA/k`, `savB/k` and `depr/k`) and this code so far:

```
savA[k_, a_] := a*k^0.5;
savB[k_, b_, c_] := b*k^(0.5) - c;
depr[k_, d_] := d*k;
Manipulate[
  If[default, 
    {s = .3, d = .02, a = 1, b = 2, d = 1, range = 600, default = False}, 
    Null];
  Column[
    {Plot[{savA[k, a], depr[k, d], savB[k, b, c]}, {k, 0, 10}, 
       PlotRange -> {-10, 10}],
     Plot[{savA[k, a]/k, depr[k, d]/k, savB[k, b, c]/k}, {k, 0, 10}, 
       PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]}],
  {a, 1, 5}, 
  {b, 5, 10}, 
  {c, 4, 10}, 
  {d, 0, 10}]
```

`savA` intersects `savB` at $k=(c/(b-a))^.5$. I want to plot the function `savA` in the interval $[0,(c/(b-a))^.5]$ and the function `savB` from $[(c/(b-a))^.5,\,\ldots]$

Answer (score 2):

Note: `savA` and `savB` intersect at `k= (c/)b-a))^2`.

You can define a new function that is equal to the maximum of the two functions and plot it:

```
savC[k_, a_, b_, c_] := Max[savA[k, a], savB[k, b, c]]

Manipulate[Plot[{savA[k, a], savB[k, b, c], savC[k, a, b, c]}, {k, 0, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Green, Blue, Directive[Thick, Red]}, 
   PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], 
 {a, 1, 5}, {b, 5, 10}, {c, 4, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also define `savC` in alternative ways such as

```
savC[k_, a_, b_, c_] := If[0 < k < (c/(b - a))^2, savA[k, a], savB[k, b, c]]
```

or (see [Piecewise](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html))

```
savC[k_, a_, b_, c_] := Piecewise[{{savA[k, a], 0 < k < (c/(b- a))^2}}, savB[k, b, c]];
```

**Update:** Maybe you meant this:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{ConditionalExpression[savA[k, a], 0 <= k < (c/(b - a))^2], 
  ConditionalExpression[savB[k, b, c], (c/(b - a))^2 <= k]}, 
  {k, 0,  10}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRange -> {0, 15}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], 
 {a, 1, 5}, {b, 5, 10}, {c, 4, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]